# Java scope modifiers in private nested class

Tags: java, scope, coding-style

Suppose I have some java code as follows:

```
public class MainClass {
  private static class NestedClass {
    <modifier> int field;
  }
}
```

Does the modifier do anything? IE is there any difference between saying `public int field` vs `private int field` since in both cases the field is only accessible in `MainClass`? What's the standard style guideline for code like this? I understand that if `NestedClass` wasn't private then the modifier might differentiate scope but since it is private the valid access patterns for field will be the same no matter what the modifier is, correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Outer class**, can access it's members **(inner class)**.
You can use the access specifiers for the **inner class** (**nested class**) if you wants  to give **restrictions** to some external class which are accessing it

Answer (score 0):

The **MainClass** can access all the members of the **NestedClass** regardless of their modifier.

Access Modifier in **NestedClass** is used only to restrict any external class to access the variables or methods of the **NestedClass**.